# Enable minor mode for specific files

Tags: minor-mode, visual-line-mode

I have a specific file which I want to always open with visual-line-mode activated. This file cannot be distinguished from others for which I want visual-line-mode deactivated, either by file name/extension or by its contents. For example, running `file(1)` on the file in question will give the same result as it would on lots of my other files.

At the moment, I am using `# -*- eval: (visual-line-mode t); -*-` in the first line of the file. This is less than ideal because every time I open the file I need to confirm I want to eval this code. The file should just open in visual-line-mode without asking for
confirmation. What is the best way to achieve this?

A perfect answer would not require me to add anything to my `.emacs` and would be applicable to other modes besides visual-line.

Comment: I fear that the available solution space under those constraints (no eval warning, no distinct filename pattern, and no Lisp code) is the empty set. You almost certainly need to find a way to live with changing at least one.

Comment: The confirmation warning should provide an option to 'permanently mark these values as safe' by pressing `!`? Isn't that the solution you are looking for? You would only have to do this once for every new variable(-list) you are setting. You could also set the `safe-local-variable-values` directly, as explained in the ['Safety of File Variables' section of the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html).

Comment: @PhilHudson Look as though you are right.

Comment: @dalanicolai Thanks for that. It does modify my .emacs to do that but I suppose I can live with it.

Comment: There is a way: Report a bug. `(visual-line-mode t)` should have the `safe-function` property. If it has this property no confirmation is needed before evaluation. Report this and maybe they add this property in the next Emacs version.

Comment: The `eval` isn't necessary. `# -*- visual-line-mode: t -*-` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent future modification of your init file (by `customize`) by defining a separate file to hold `custom` settings (a la `safe-local-variable-values`). At the beginning of your init file do something like

```lisp
;; nb. `custom-file` is an Emacs variable see `C-h v custom-file`
(setq custom-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/custom.el"))
```

and at the end of your init file add

```lisp
(load custom-file)
```

(Ok, it doesn't *have* to be split like that, but that's how I organize my init file. I do recommend having the call to `load` at the end of your init file though.)

Note that `custom-file` itself is a `customize`-able variable, so I encourage you to read it's help via `C-h v custom-file`.

If you do this, you should obviously move any `custom` settings to your new file, or delete them. This is great in situations where your init files are read-only, or you keep them under version control (don't forget to add your new custom-file to your VC's ignore list).